# Laravel 5.6 cache storing thousands of values all called :timer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have set my laravel 5.6 app to use the database cache driver and before I even started using the cache I noticed the table was filling up at an alarming rate. It is creating two entries over and over again seemingly automatically even when the app isn't receiving any traffic. One won't have a key and the other will be called timer e.g

my_app_cache014fadcce01ca4d2cb1f2b9a207c7c71b2a91082
my_app_cache014fadcce01ca4d2cb1f2b9a207c7c71b2a91082:timer

The one with no key will have a value such as i:2;
The :timer one will have a value such as i:1544528601;

It's creating about 40 records per minute.

I've done a search of the website files and found `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/RateLimiter.php` which seems to be the offending file but I don't really understand what it's doing. If I'm not actively using the cache then what is there to rate limit?

Answer (score 2):

Found the cause. This bug report pointed in the right direction:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15152

It is caused by API routes using the default api middleware which applies throttling. I stopped using throttling and it's no longer happening